# Custom FB Login Flow

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, manual

Good day all. I follow the "manually build a login flow" ([Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)) instructions to create my login. When I try to log in, though, it doesn't ask me to re-authenticate permissions. Is there something wrong with how I'm looking at this or is there something wrong with my link? Please see the URL I'm using below:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/v9.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[app_id]&redirect_uri=[local_redirect_uri]&state=[state]&response_type=token,granted_scopes&scope=[comma_delimited_list_of_permissions]">Test Login Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following on the page that was pointed to with "next"

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/[user-ID]/permissions?access_token=[access_token]
```

with a DELETE request.

I did it all using the php cURL library.